# How do you use ng-repeat with a directive/template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use ng-repeat to iterate over an array I've defined. This would write out a custom Element, which has a Directive/template to replace it's HTML.

When I don't use ng-repeat, the custom Attributes are picked up in the template, and filled in, e.g.

```
<my-custom-elm customAttr1="customVal1" customAttr2="customVal2"></my-custom-elm>
<my-custom-elm customAttr1="customVal3" customAttr2="customVal4"></my-custom-elm>
```

and:

```
app.directive('myCustomElm', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            customAttr1: '@',
            customAttr2: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="{{ customAttr1 }}">{{ customAttr2 }}</div>'
    }
});
```

would write out:

```
<div class="customVal1">customVal2</div>
<div class="customVal3">customVal4</div>
```

However, when I try to do this iteratively using ng-repeat, as so:

```
<my-custom-elm ng-repeat="x in jsArr" customAttr1="{{ x.customAttr1 }}" customAttr2="{{ x.customAttr2 }}"></my-custom-elm>
```

The placeholders recieve no value. The HTML attributes are written to the element, so it's just the placeholders that I'm referencing poorly, for some reason.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert camel case to dash delimit for attribute as well
`customAttr1` > `custom-attr1`

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('Test', Test)
  .directive('myCustomElm', myCustomElm);
  
function Test($scope) {
  $scope.jsArr = [
    {customAttr1: 'foo', customAttr2: 'bar'},
    {customAttr1: 'oof', customAttr2: 'rab'}
  ]
}

function myCustomElm() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      customAttr1: '@',
      customAttr2: '@'
    },
    template: '<div class="{{ customAttr1 }}">{{ customAttr2 }}</div>'
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <my-custom-elm ng-repeat="x in jsArr" custom-attr1="{{ x.customAttr1 }}" custom-attr2="{{ x.customAttr2 }}"></my-custom-elm>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using "=' instead of "@" inside scope:{}.